# Changing the definition of an existing field does not work on another server

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In this location `suitecrm/custom/Extension/modules/Color/Ext/Vardefs/custom_field_level_name.php`

I am trying the following code in order to customize an existing field definition

```
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['type'] = 'varchar';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['len'] = '255';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['audited'] = true;
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['vname'] = 'LBL_LEVEL_NAME';
```

This is working in local in my dev pc

But when I deploy to production this customization is not working. When I Repair and rebuild I am expecting the sql script to synchronize the vardefs with the database but does not show the ALTER command to modify the level_name field in the colors table I have done this with other fields and so far without problems.

Why the customization of the definition of an existing field does not work on another server?

Thanks your comments...

**Update**

I have come to understand that the problem is related to the way in which the file `suitecrm/custom/modules/Color/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.ext.php` is generated  The content of this file is different on the remote server than on my local development pc. The custom definitions in the field in my local pc and after repair in the file `suitecrm/custom/modules/Color/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.ext.php` are located at the end of the file so that it overwrites the original definition of the field. While on the remote server the custom definition is located at the beginning of the file so that they are overwritten by the original definition of the file

For example in my local file content has this order

```
//...

$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name'] = array(
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'level_name',
    'vname' => 'LBL_LEVEL_NAME',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'massupdate' => 0,
    'no_default' => false,
    'comments' => '',
    'help' => '',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => false,
    'inline_edit' => true,
    'reportable' => true,
    'unified_search' => false,
    'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
    'len' => '255',
    'size' => '20',
);

$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['type'] = 'varchar';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['len'] = '255';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['audited'] = true;
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['vname'] = 'LBL_LEVEL_NAME';

//...
```

While in remote has this order

```
//...

$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['type'] = 'varchar';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['len'] = '255';
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['audited'] = true;
$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name']['vname'] = 'LBL_LEVEL_NAME';

$dictionary['Color']['fields']['level_name'] = array(
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'level_name',
    'vname' => 'LBL_LEVEL_NAME',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'massupdate' => 0,
    'no_default' => false,
    'comments' => '',
    'help' => '',
    'importable' => 'true',
    'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
    'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
    'audited' => false,
    'inline_edit' => true,
    'reportable' => true,
    'unified_search' => false,
    'merge_filter' => 'disabled',
    'len' => '255',
    'size' => '20',
);

//...
```

In order to correct the error at remote server I deleted the file `suitecrm/custom/modules/Color/Ext/Vardefs/vardefs.ext.php` and after repair I expected the order to be corrected but it is not. Is there anything I can do to ensure that the custom definitions are located after the ones originally defined?

Thanks again for your comments

Comment: Have you checked if you have database permissions (ALTER) in the production server using the production database user ?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am getting access as root in production database, I did almost the same for other fields but in this case this is happening.

Comment: I just added new information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is either

- Always create fields on both instances and then merge with git
- Sync fields_metadata + changed files and then do the repair and rebuild.

This is one of the limitations of SuiteCRM/SugarCRM development, you can't just do stuff with code, some field information is stored in the `fields_metadata` table.

Sometimes it just works for some types of field, to be honest, I don't know exactly why.

Comment: Thanks for answering. We use customize vardefs in order to create fields or modify the definition of them and thus avoid synchronizing fields_meta_data. As the process of customizing vardefs does not create fields in fields_meta_data and does not create _cstm tables. A clarification, about point one **Always create fields in both instances and then merge with git** do you mean to create the field in local (dev pc) and in production or test?

Comment: Custom fields from studio is a pain , all you need to create fields from code.

Comment: ie for leads , put your vardefs in  custom/Extension/modules/Leads/Ext/Vardefs/any_field.php

Comment: yes @user615274 that what I meant.  Creating from code usually is faster for devs, but some fields cannot just be created from code, don't remember exactly which error we came to find when fields where code-only, something with related to the API, but that was 1yr ago, things might have changed.